# Is it possible to generate sudoku games with LaTeX?

Tags: tables, programming

I am a fan of sudoku and I was wondering if it is possible to randomly generate sudoku tables with their solutions in LaTeX. I see a few problems in the generation of numbers in the tables, but, sincerely, I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: The first step is to have an algorithm to produce Sudoku tables. If you have that, in pseudo-code, or any language you like if that's easier, then someone will probably step forward an implement it.

Comment: I suggest to use the [sudoku](http://ctan.org/pkg/sudoku) package.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

a package, [`sudokubundle`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sudokubundle), by peter wilson is on ctan.  this appears to do what you're asking.  it requires the `random` package to generate puzzle data.

Comment: I will look into it.

Comment: I'm glad to see some answers get votes even if they don't include screenshots. (The default seems to be one has to include them in order to get votes....)

Answer (score 15):

For typesetting Sudokus (well, LaTeX is mainly for typesetting, while calculations can be done for example with Lua, or pgf which provides a random number generator), Roberto Bonvallet has contributed a [Sudoku example](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/sudoku/) to the [TikZ gallery](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/).

[image: Sudoku example]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\newcounter{row}
\newcounter{col}

\newcommand\setrow[9]{
  \setcounter{col}{1}
  \foreach \n in {#1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, #7, #8, #9} {
    \edef\x{\value{col} - 0.5}
    \edef\y{9.5 - \value{row}}
    \node[anchor=center] at (\x, \y) {\n};
    \stepcounter{col}
  }
  \stepcounter{row}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]

  \begin{scope}
    \draw (0, 0) grid (9, 9);
    \draw[very thick, scale=3] (0, 0) grid (3, 3);

    \setcounter{row}{1}
    \setrow { }{2}{ }  {5}{ }{1}  { }{9}{ }
    \setrow {8}{ }{ }  {2}{ }{3}  { }{ }{6}
    \setrow { }{3}{ }  { }{6}{ }  { }{7}{ }

    \setrow { }{ }{1}  { }{ }{ }  {6}{ }{ }
    \setrow {5}{4}{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{1}{9}
    \setrow { }{ }{2}  { }{ }{ }  {7}{ }{ }

    \setrow { }{9}{ }  { }{3}{ }  { }{8}{ }
    \setrow {2}{ }{ }  {8}{ }{4}  { }{ }{7}
    \setrow { }{1}{ }  {9}{ }{7}  { }{6}{ }

    \node[anchor=center] at (4.5, -0.5) {Unsolved Sudoku};
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[xshift=12cm]
    \draw (0, 0) grid (9, 9);
    \draw[very thick, scale=3] (0, 0) grid (3, 3);

    \setcounter{row}{1}
    \setrow { }{2}{ }  {5}{ }{1}  { }{9}{ }
    \setrow {8}{ }{ }  {2}{ }{3}  { }{ }{6}
    \setrow { }{3}{ }  { }{6}{ }  { }{7}{ }

    \setrow { }{ }{1}  { }{ }{ }  {6}{ }{ }
    \setrow {5}{4}{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{1}{9}
    \setrow { }{ }{2}  { }{ }{ }  {7}{ }{ }

    \setrow { }{9}{ }  { }{3}{ }  { }{8}{ }
    \setrow {2}{ }{ }  {8}{ }{4}  { }{ }{7}
    \setrow { }{1}{ }  {9}{ }{7}  { }{6}{ }

    \node[anchor=center] at (4.5, -0.5) {Solved Sudoku};

    \begin{scope}[blue, font=\sffamily\slshape]
      \setcounter{row}{1}
      \setrow {4}{ }{6}  { }{7}{ }  {3}{ }{8}
      \setrow { }{5}{7}  { }{9}{ }  {1}{4}{ }
      \setrow {1}{ }{9}  {4}{ }{8}  {2}{ }{5}

      \setrow {9}{7}{ }  {3}{8}{5}  { }{2}{4}
      \setrow { }{ }{3}  {7}{2}{6}  {8}{ }{ }
      \setrow {6}{8}{ }  {1}{4}{9}  { }{5}{3}

      \setrow {7}{ }{4}  {6}{ }{2}  {5}{ }{1}
      \setrow { }{6}{5}  { }{1}{ }  {9}{3}{ }
      \setrow {3}{ }{8}  { }{5}{ }  {4}{ }{2}
    \end{scope}

  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess this only displays the sudoku but does not generate it. Its a good idea though. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I would recommend not using 'mathpazo', as it doesn't seem to be required and globally changes the formatting for your whole document.

Comment: @ChrisJefferson Thanks! It was loaded in the original code by Roberto.

Answer (score 5):

For typesetting Sudokus, you can also use the [logicpuzzle bundle](https://bitbucket.org/kleberj/logicpuzzle/wiki/Home) [[CTAN]](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/logicpuzzle).

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{lpsudoku}
    \setrow{9}{{},2,6,{},{},{},{},{},{}}
    \setrow{8}{{},{},{},{},{},{},1,7,{}}
    \setrow{7}{{},{},3,1,{},6,{},{},{}}
    \setrow{6}{{},6,{},{},5,{},8,{},3}
    \setrow{5}{{},{},9,2,6,1,7,{},{}}
    \setrow{4}{5,{},4,{},8,{},{},6,{}}
    \setrow{3}{{},{},{},8,{},4,3,{},{}}
    \setrow{2}{{},4,8,{},{},{},{},{},{}}
    \setrow{1}{{},{},{},{},{},{},9,4,{}}
    \end{lpsudoku}
    \hspace{1.5cm}
    \begin{lpsudoku}
    \setrow{9}{1,2,6,5,7,8,4,3,9}
    \setrow{8}{4,8,5,9,3,2,1,7,6}
    \setrow{7}{7,9,3,1,4,6,5,8,2}
    \setrow{6}{2,6,1,4,5,7,8,9,3}
    \setrow{5}{8,3,9,2,6,1,7,5,4}
    \setrow{4}{5,7,4,3,8,9,2,6,1}
    \setrow{3}{6,5,2,8,9,4,3,1,7}
    \setrow{2}{9,4,8,7,1,3,6,2,5}
    \setrow{1}{3,1,7,6,2,5,9,4,8}
  \end{lpsudoku}
\end{center}
```

[image: Sudoku]

You can use the [createlpsudoku](http://logicpuzzle.square7.de/createlpsudoku) bash script to transfer exported Sudokus from e.g. HoDoKu or QQwing into `lpsudoku` environments. See: [How to create a Sudoku magazine](http://logicpuzzle.square7.de/sudoku_magazine)

With the [lpsmag](http://logicpuzzle.square7.de/lpsmag) bash script, you can even produce your own [Sudoku magazines](https://bitbucket.org/kleberj/logicpuzzle/downloads/lpsmag.pdf) with solutions!
Whenever you run the script, you have a new magazine.